# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.messenger.messenger.Friends

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show Firebase data into RecyclerView. The firebase consist of DatabaseReference "Friends" and have users id as you can see in below pic,
[image]

I want to get data of an specifc id by this code,

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
queryFriends = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);
```

In the above line, the .child(mCurrent_user_id) create **fatal error** and app gets crashed. I've log the mCurrent_user_id by below code which give correct result as same in **Friends** database reference.

```
Log.d("sdfsdf", mCurrent_user_id);
```

the log result is `com.example.messenger.messenger D/sdfsdf: wed5qPTCdcQVzVlRcBrMo1NX43v1`

Recycler code:

```
queryFriends = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);
        queryFriends.keepSynced(true);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Friends> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Friends>()
                        .setQuery(queryFriends, Friends.class)
                        .build();

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public FriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
                // layout called R.layout.message for each item
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.adapter_users_activity_layout, parent, false);

                return new FriendsViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(final FriendsViewHolder friendsViewHolder, int position, Friends friends) {
                friendsViewHolder.setDate(friends.getDate());
}
```

Viewholder:

```
public static class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setDate(String date){
            TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
            userStatusView.setText(date);
        }

        public void setName(String name){
            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
            userNameView.setText(name);
        }
```

ExceptioN:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.messenger.messenger.Friends
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source)
```

Rules:
[image]

Comment: can you give your logcat or fatal error's name ?

Comment: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.messenger.messenger.Friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these lines causes the issue:

```
userNameView.setText(name);
userStatusView.setText(date);
```

Your `ViewHolder` has problem with setting data into views. Try setting those in `onBindViewHolder()` method.

**Update:** Try something like this as your `Viewholder`:

```
public class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textName;
    TextView textDate;

    public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
        textDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);


    }

}
```

And this, inside `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
friendsViewHolder.textName.setDate(friends.getName());
friendsViewHolder.textDate.setDate(friends.getDate());
```

I assumed your `Adapter` has setters-getters for get-set Date-Name.

Comment: how i can do this?

Comment: again same error Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.messenger.messenger.Friends

Comment: control cannot goes into OnBindViewHolder()

Comment: when i use this then program works fine queryFriends = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends");

Comment: but i need child of "Friend"

Comment: this gives error  queryFriends = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);

Comment: fatal error gone by your code but still not showig data

Comment: i logged  by this Log.d("sdfsdfsdf", options.getSnapshots().toString()); which gives [] empty array

Comment: is there any problem in database rules? please see my updated question

Comment: No seems fine. I'm guessing that the query has problem. Let's check with: `child("Friends").orderByKey().equalTo(mCurrent_user.getUid())` this should work.